# Loading data into Mysql table

Tags: mysql, file-io

I'm quite sure this question probably have been posted here somewhere but I can't find it. My problem seems a bit different. I tried loading a `.txt` file from my local computer into `MYSQL` table but the output comes out really scrambled. The data are flying all over the place and not in order as I want it to be.

Could anyone please explain why it is so and a way out?

I used the query; `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \home\minilab\desktop\data.txt1.txt INTO clientrecord`;

Comment: Can you add a few lines from your text file so we can see what the content looks like?

Comment: Is the order of the fields within the file the same as the order of the fields within the database?

Comment: Few lines from my table; id firstname lastname customer_id address
                                       1   bright  brighter 110  sprengelstr 1

Answer (score 0):

Hope txt values in a line match the fields in table, If the data are separated by ',' use fields terminated by ',' or if separated by tab use fields terminated by '\t' and add lines terminated by '\n'

also share the sample data of ur infile

Ex:

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \home\minilab\desktop\data.txt1.txt INTO
>   clientrecord fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';

if you not using the proper formating the values will scattered across the table.

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html